# Swift array: how to append element references in order to update element later on from a synch request?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, asynchronous

[UPDATE]
I have added actual code snippet in order to make my question clear.

Say we want to store uiimages into an array, which are fetched from the internet.

I have this code snippet:

```
            // Somewhere in a loop
            {
                var story = Story()
                story.imgUrl        = "http:\(imgUrl)"

                /// Donwload image, and replace in the top
                if let imgUrl = story.imgUrl {
                    if let url = NSURL(string: imgUrl) {
                        let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url)
                        NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()) {
                            (response, data, error) -> Void in
                            if let data = data {
                                story.image = UIImage(data: data)
                                var i = 0
                                for a in self.Stories {
                                    print("iv image \(i++) is \(a.image)")
                                }


                                print("Received image for story as \(story.image) into story \(story)")
                                // Should one set the image view?
                                if let _ = self.imageView {
                                    if let indexPath = self.tableView?.indexPathForSelectedRow {
                                        if stories.count == indexPath.section {   // is that the currently selected section?
                                            self.imageView?.image = story.image
                                            self.imageView?.hidden = false
                                            print("Set imageView withstory \(story.tag.string)")
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                stories.append(story)
             }


            /// Switch data source
            self.Stories = stories
```

This doesn't store the image property value into the destination array.
Though the image is ok in the block, if I iterate through the destination array, my image is nil

```
image: Optional(<UIImage: 0x7ff14b6e4b20> size {100, 67} orientation 0 scale 1.000000))
iv image 0 is nil
```

How to achieve above functionality?

[INITIAL QUESTION]

Say we want to store element i.e UIImages which i have fetched from the internet. I have this code snippet:

```
var array = []

let imageView = UIImageView(image:nil)
array.append(imageView)

// and later or, in an synch block
imageView.image = image
```

This doesn't store the image property value in the array.

How could I do that?

Comment: why should it store the image? you only insert the imageView, what exactly are you expecting to happen?

Comment: Please try to rephrase the question. It is very hard to understand. Your code example isn’t very useful either.

Comment: I added actual code in order to ease understanding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gotcha!

The point is that Story was defined as struct. And structs are passed by values unlike classes.

To make the code working, I just changed from struct Story {} to class Story {}, and voila!